# What are the different ways to say "lonely"?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, meaning, word-request

The English word "lonely" has at least a couple different uses. A person can be lonely — we all know, and have probably felt, this meaning of the word. But also a place can be lonely. A lot of people refer to NYC and London as lonely cities.

I wanted to know, what are the different Latin words for "lonely", and what are their different connotations? I have come up with two candidates myself, *solum* and *desertum*, and I'm wondering whether *solum* is better suited to people or things, and *desertum* to places.

Is there a Latin word that has connotations similar to the English "lonely", e.g. sadness?

Comment: In what sense are NYC and London lonely? I'm not sure I understand what you are after.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Here's a use of the phrase: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-London-such-a-lonely-city-to-some-and-such-an-amazing-place-to-others. I think the sense is this: the cities are so fast-paced and competitive that people have a hard time forming real, lasting friendships. But I'm not 100% sure of my take.

Comment: Fortunately the word I ended up suggesting seems general enough to cover that. But of course there might another idiomatic choice of words one should know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a lonely place I would use the noun *solitudo*.
[L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=solitudo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) describes it, among other things, as "loneliness", "solitude (of a person or place)", and "a lonely place".
This word refers to the state of loneliness in a broader sense than any English word.
I would probably use this word for all of the cases you describe.

If you want to cry "how lonely!" as you did in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm), one possible Latin translation would be *qualis solitudo!*
There might be other ways of forming such exclamations with nouns, but *qualis* has famous precedent.
Remember the famous *qualis artifex pereo!* by Nero?

You may view it as a problem or an opportunity, but bear in mind that *solitudo* is a noun, unlike the English "lonely".
If you want an adjective instead, I would recommend the related [*solitarius*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=solitarius&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
I would be ready to use this for all of your example cases, but that doesn't mean that there wouldn't be more idiomatic choices for some other situations.